# How to get keys of object (key-value) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, object

I want get key of object, like Javasript method Object.keys.
here is my object:

```
public object OjbectExample { get; set; }

ObjectExample is:
{"en":"Some Value", "fr":"Value is here"}
```

in JS i can easy to get key of object, but in C# i don't have idea to do that.

i want convert it into string: "$[en|Some Value][fr|Value is here]"
Any idea for this?

Comment: What's the runtime type of `ObjectExample`?

Comment: It is ```Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Newton` is your friend,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string test = "{'en':'Some Value', 'fr':'Value is here'}"; // this is your json input

     ObjectTest converted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectTest>(test); // deserialize json input to your custom object
}
```

Here is the example object;

```
public class ObjectTest {
     public string en { get; set; }
     public string fr { get; set; }
}
```

Result;[image]

**Or** you can take `Keys` and `Values` from `JObject` like this,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      string test = "{'en':'Some Value', 'fr':'Value is here'}"; // this is your json input

      JObject converted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(test);

      if (converted != null)
      {
         Dictionary<string, string> keyValueMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> keyValuePair in converted)
         {
              keyValueMap.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value.ToString());
         }
      }
}
```

Result;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create your own type

```
public class OjbectExample
{
    public string Key_ { get; set; }
    public string Value_{ get; set; }
}
```

Then use it anywhere

```
ObjectExample obj = new ObjectExample(){Key_  = "en", Value_ = "Some Value"};
```